# failure while checking if template exists on filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I was configuring file beat and pushing JSON data to a particular index.
can anyone help what is wrong with the filebeat or elastic setup.

> ERROR [publisher_pipeline_output] pipeline/output.go:154  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://x.x.x.x:9200)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: error loading template: failure while checking if template exists: 405 Method Not Allowed:

Comment: Which versions of elastic and filebeat are you using? Can you share the filebeat config? Can you verify the elastic is reachable with a simple API call?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with a different version of filebeat image. Previously I was using 7.17.1 (with elasticsearch ver 7.6.1 and kibana ver 7.6.1). I changed the docker image ver for filebeat from docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.17.1 (with same elasticsearch and kibana version)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).